# RelativePattern not available

Tags: visual-studio, workspace

I'm trying to make my vscode extension compatible with multi-root workspaces - and I'd like to get files from a specific workspace.
Problem is - in my version this type "RelativePattern" is not available - and I have no clue on how to make it available.  As far as I know, I updated all libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an old version of the API definitions. To update it, update the vscode engine version in your `package.json`:

```
{
    "engines": {
         "vscode": "^1.21"
    }
}
```

Then run the post install script again:

```
npm run postinstall
```

or:

```
node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install
```

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!